# How to read .property value from .properties file if the key as number in sprigboot

Tags: spring-boot

If the value in property is like `30=BOTSWANA`, then in the spring boot application it's giving only number as `result(30)`?

How to get value in springboot app?

Configuration

```
@PropertySource("classpath:locale.properties") 
public class LocaleReader { 
    @Inject private Environment env; public String getPropertyByKey(String key){
        return env.getProperty(key); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:locale.properties")
public class LocaleReader {
 
 @Inject
 private Environment env;
 public String getPropertyByKey(String key) {
  return env.getProperty(key);
 }
}

Comment: how do you retrieve it? you use Value annotation?

Comment: You want it should return BOTSWANA against key 30

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question, which is better than trying to add code as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want key to be numeric this is what I have tried and its working.
taken a CommandLineRunner to print the value

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CommandLineRunner implements org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${age}")
    private String age;

    @Value("${25}")
    private String country;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("my age is ===================" + age);
System.out.println("my country is ===================" + country);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
age=30
25=US
```